# Ant filter tokenize with 2 or 3 tokens per line

Tags: regex, ant

I have a document with lines following this pattern:

```
"key1", "value1", "trash1"
"key2", "value2"
"key3", "value3", "trash3"
```

I need (a filter) to remove the third token of a line, if any.

```
"key1", "value1"
"key2", "value2"
"key3", "value3"
```

How can I do that with Apache Ant?

> **Note**: Apache Ant does not support lookarounds in regular expressions.

Comment: The code snippet is the result of what is currently working. I cannot find a solution to 'ignore everything after the second occurance of ","'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match three tokens and replace with groups.
Simple search with

`("[^"]*?")(, "[^"]*?")(?:, "[^"]*?")?` and replace with `\1\2` will do the job.

First two groups are captured. Third one is non-capturing group.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IHodgn/1/)

Code for Apache Ant would be as following:

```
<replaceregexp file="${src}/build.properties"
           match='("[^"]*?")(, "[^"]*?")(?:, "[^"]*?")?'
           replace="\1\2"
           byline="true"
/>
```